# .RDLC and VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a classlibrary project, then add a new empty report .rdlc, when compiled throw this error

> "The report definition is not valid. Details: the report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.sqlserver.reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded"

This cannot be the reportviewer because is a dll, what should do i for fix it?

the reportviewer 2010 is also installed

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue today and I found solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/47ecd315-6372-46cf-b319-df098334fc74). Thanks Jim Lafler.

My "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets" file had changed

In the top was:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" AssemblyName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

and it should have been:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" AssemblyName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the namespace. Open your **.rdlc** file in text/xml editor and change the namespace to

```
 
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"
```